# Does this "collecting royal souls" plotline have a common origin?

Tags: inspiration

A few works seem to share a rather specific plotline, regarding the collection of the souls of various royal bloodlines.

For instance, in *The Bone Witch* and its sequels, by Rin  Chupeco, part of the process for creating the all-powerful shadowglass (particularly capable of raising the dead) requires using the souls of members of the five royal bloodlines that defeated a great evil long ago.

In the TV series *Ice Fantasy* (幻城),  in order to activate the Hidden Lotus and attain great power (particularly to raise the dead), one must acquire the souls of members of the royal bloodlines that defeated a great evil long before (possibly even five of them).

These seem similar enough that it makes me wonder whether they might have **drawn from the same mythological sources.** It's a much more specific idea than simply "royal people have magical power," [such as curing scrofula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_touch); even different from the idea of the true royal heir being qualified to wield some artifact, like a sword in a rock.

Is there some original work, or even a historical belief held to be factual, that inspired these (and other) examples? Is there some mythological story that these works are referencing?

Comment: The goal of every Dark Souls game.

Comment: Yeah, that could be another example. It seems more likely to be inspired by the same source than to be the source in itself, though.

Comment: I should have specified that I was just including another example. It's not the source.